# Problem when importing files from the Downloads folder to the internal memory - API 30

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-external-storage, scoped-storage

I have the following situation, where everything works perfectly on all APIs except API 30, i.e. Android 11. Namely, I first export my textual and audio files from the internal storage to the external storage, i.e. in the Downloads folder. It all works without problems on all APIs. However, when I want to import the same files from the Downloads folder into the internal storage of my app, works as it should on all APIs, but on API 30 - Android 11 it only creates the Text and Audio folder but does not import the files. **It is interesting to note that mp3 files are imported, but text files are not.** What do you think is the problem and is there a solution, thank you.

```
    restore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                if (SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (checkPermission()) {
                        try {
                            // create Text dir
                            File sdcardDic = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                            File dirDic = new File(sdcardDic.getAbsolutePath() + "/Text/");
                            dirDic.mkdir();
                            FileOutputStream dic = null;
                            try {
                                dic = new FileOutputStream(dirDic);
                                dic.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // create Audio dir
                            File sdcardAudio = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                            File dirAudio = new File(sdcardAudio.getAbsolutePath() + "/Audio/");
                            dirAudio.mkdir();
                            FileOutputStream audio = null;
                            try {
                                audio = new FileOutputStream(dirAudio);
                                audio.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // import file from Downloads dir
                            File sdcard = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                            File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath());

                            appRecovery(new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))),
                                    new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()));

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        requestPermission();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


public void appRecovery(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation)
        throws IOException {

    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceLocation.listFiles().length; i++) {

            appRecovery(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

        // copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: `from the internal memory to the external memory, ` ? Can you first explain (in your post) what you consider to be internal and external memory. Maybe you can even speak about storage locations.

Comment: `when I want to import the same files from the Downloads folder into the internal memory of my app, ` Please mention to which storage location. Your app does not have internal memory to begin with..

Comment: `dirDic.mkdir();` So you made dicDir a directory. `dic = new FileOutputStream(dirDic);` You cannot open a FileOutputStream for a directory.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }` You will have that exception but you blindly continue as if nothing has happened. Instead you should display a Toast() to the usere an stop or return.

Comment: First of all, thank you for reply to my post! I first copy the text file from the app to the public Downloads folder, after that I want to return the same text file to my app from the public Downloads folder (here is the problem).

Comment: Did you mention the storage locations i asked for?

Comment: Yes, I first saved the text file in the Downloads folder and it's there, but now I'm trying to return the same file from the Downloads folder to the app, but it won't